# ASP.Net Custom Control - override onkeyup

Tags: asp.net, onkeyup

I am having one problem which as simple as it may seem, gives me a lot of trouble. I have defined a custom control for a textbox in ASP.NET which has built-in the onkeyup attribute. My problem is that when using this control i want to override onkeyup, but it seems not to be working. My source code is the following:

```
this.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "javascript:" + onKeyUp + ";"); // for the custom control
```

and when using it

```
< myControl:SpecialTextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"/>
```

in code behind I did set

```
txtValue.Attributes.Add("onKeyUp", "DefaultValue();");
```

However, I keep on getting the onkeyup defined in the custom control instead of the more specific one. 
Are there any solutions to this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `txtValue.Attributes["onKeyUp"] = "DefaultValue();";` in codebehing of your page, this will override your custom control one.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a property to your `CustomControl`:

```
public string OnClientKeyUp { get { /**/ } set { /**/ }
```

Set the default value in `OnInit` so you can override in a page later (e.g. `Page_Load`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to adding a property on your user contorl, something like this:

```
public string KeyUp
{
    get
    {
        if (txtValue.Attributes["onKeyUp"] == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return txtValue.Attributes["onKeyUp"]
    }
    set
    {
        txtValue.Attributes["onKeyUp"] = value;
    }
}
```

And on your server side asp.net tag you can call this property and set the value:

```
<myControl:SpecialTextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" KeyUp="DefaultValue();" />
```